# Ionic 4 Angular 7 Simple Remote HTTP Request CORS

Tags: angular, cors, ionic4

I'm a little new to ionic and angular and am trying to figure out how to send a simple HTTP request to a remote server while bypassing CORS. My initial solution was to do this:

```
this.httpClient.get<MyObj>("/api");
```

And then I created a proxy.config.json with this content:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://real-remote-host/",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

This works great when I'm doing an `ng serve`. However, I go to build an android APK using `ionic cordova build android` and then this code no longer works. It appears as if the proxy only works when running via a `serve` command, but not via a `build` command. I surely have to be missing something since a simple HTTP request can't be this hard.

Also, the remote host cannot be changed, so please don't suggest changing to allow CORS from the remote host.

Comment: That's right, the proxy is part of the webpack dev server (see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)) and isn't part of the production build output.

Comment: Okay, so I can throw the proxy.config.json solution away since it won't work for a production build. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to get this working on Android. It is based on this tutorial provided by Ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http. However, their article is far from complete.

The biggest thing the tutorial is missing is that you need to include the HTTP as a provider in your angular app module.

```
import { HTTP } from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";
...
@NgModule(
...
   providers: [
      ...
      HTTP
      ...
   ]
...
)
...
```

The second problem I ran into was that it kept saying the "plugin_not_installed". This is because I happened to be calling the `this.http.get()` before it was ready to be used. To resolve this, I needed to:

```
...
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.http.get(...);
});
...
```

Because the REST service I was hitting is HTTP and not HTTPS and because I'm targeting SDK 28+, I needed to include this snippet in my config.xml. The main thing is the usesCleartextTraffic needs to be set to true in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
...
<platform name="android">
...
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
...
</platform>
...
```

Also note that this solution does not work for the browser, so you'd have to use the proxy.config.json solution previously mentioned for testing purposes. You can use the `this.platform.is("android")` to check if it's android. I can't verify if this will work properly on ios, but the plugin page says it supports android and ios.